# программа на C#

Tags: c#

Как найти дату (и желательно время) в текстовом редакторе с помощью программы C# и вывести на консоль только дату ?
Выглядит он так, но это всего маленькая часть.

```
30.01.2014 10:32:44 36324 36324 36324 36324 2
03.02.2014 18:44:36 37650 37650 37650 37650 10
03.02.2014 18:44:44 36413 36413 36413 36413 10
11.02.2014 17:33:36 37300 37300 37300 37300 1
```

(простите за  громоздкость)

Comment: Независимо от языка программирования, когда есть задача найти что то в тексте всегда используют [регулярные выражения (regexp)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: это конечно круто, но 1) это часть программы 2) этих строк у меня пару тысяч

Comment: @ConstantinePl Да что вы говорите?! Когда мне нужно найти что-то в тексте я использую функции поиска в тексте. И в данном случае хватит тупых strchr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Прочитайте построчно ваш текст(можете и не построчно, тут вариантов много)
- Выберите строку и воспользуйтесь методом [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) и
  разделите во пробелу: `" "` или регуляркой, например [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Найденую строку с датой, скормите методу
  [Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx)

Comment: извеняюсь не правильно поставил задачу нужно вывести на консоль только дату (и желательно время)

Comment: @ильявитюк, а в чем проблема? алгоритм описан, функции которые нужно использовать тоже, вам осталось просто записать все вместе

Comment: @ильявитюк задачу поставить вы можете на каком нить сайте фрилансеров, тут вы можете попросить поделится участников сообщества знанием. В своем ответе я поделился знанием о всех необходимых методах для того, что бы вы могли самостоятельно решить эту задачу. Для вывода в консоль текста, вы можете воспользоваться методом Console.WriteLine(dateTime);

Comment: Мстислав Павлов спасибо то что надо